# Show top 10 distinct users in Sharepoint 2010 list based on another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, caml-query, conditional

I am having a Sharepoint 2010 site where I'm having a List named `UserRank` which has columns `User` of type people & group and `Datetime`.

After each custom email webpart an entry to this list is added.

There will hence be large number of entries in this list at the end of year for all users.

I am having another list name as `Top Users`. In this list I want to show the 10 users who got highest number of entries, with distinct and count for current year.

Say:

```
User 1 has 200 entries, 
User 2 has 170 entries
....
```

What approach I should use here: Do I need to code in Visual Studio or can I do this by using only Sharepoint settings, or is Sharepoint Designer helpful?

Comment: Have you already tried to solve in the same list? Using user grouping and collapsing groups.

Comment: No, how to do that ? Do I need to write code somewhere?

Comment: I think you need code, C# and Visual Studio,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to self question, may be helpful to others:

The approach is, in UserRank list I added Count columns as numeric. After each email from webpart the user count get increment. if user exist then his count increments. if not exist then add user with count 1. Each user entry has its incremental date in datetime column. Now create view on page where I wanted to show Top 10 users. In this view added Year Coluns which is linked with datetime column. In Sort section added condition based on Year first and then based on count. In Filter section added year to be displayed. That's it.
[image]